# Postgress by a CASE with DISTINCT in select

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like below getting the error -  'SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list'

```
 select distinct name
    from fruits
  order by case
   when name = 'mango' then 1
    else 2
   end
```

This results 4 records, say

```
apple, mango, pear and grape
```

How can I make sure I get Mango as the first record always and the rest follow. I tried using the case statement, but not able to get the desired results. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It is postgress

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should accomplish what you describe as needing.

```
select distinct 
       name,
       case name when 'Mango' then 1 else 2 end as fruitOrder
from   fruits
order by 
       fruitOrder
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to always have `'mango'` in first position, no matter the other rows, this could be a way:

```
with fruits(name) as (
    select 'apple' from dual union all
    select 'mango' from dual union all
    select 'pear'  from dual union all
    select 'grape' from dual
)
select name
from fruits
order by case
            when name = 'mango' then 1
            else 2
         end
```

If you need to add a `DISTINCT`, this should work:

```
select distinct name,
        case
            when name = 'mango' then 1
            else 2
         end orderCol
from fruits
order by orderCol
```

Comment: Sorry about incomplete info, this is on a postgress Database and I am getting an error when i use the query you recommended above.ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = boolean

Comment: Please edit the tags of the question to match your DBMS

Comment: @user747291 - The CTE is just for demo purposes. They key part is the `ORDER BY CASE ....`. [Skimming the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) I think that should work for you.

Comment: I tried this, when i add a distinct i am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you 'Mango' followed by the others in order;

```
WITH get_rows AS
(SELECT DISTINCT item_type
   FROM the_item)
SELECT item_type
  FROM 
(SELECT 1 as seq, item_type
   FROM get_rows
  WHERE item_type = 'Mango'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 as seq, item_type
   FROM get_rows
  WHERE item_type <> 'Mango')
ORDER BY seq, item_type
```

Comment: Seems like overkill :-) A simple CASE should do it.

Comment: @Leigh - Only advantage is that the non-Mango items are then listed in order afterwards. However, you're probably right.

Comment: True, sorting by the rank/seq only does not make much sense. The additional column in the `order by` should be applied, regardless of which approach is used.